# Why does jpa select query stuck?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have query which to count data, and it's a simple one, here's the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(o.id) FROM Order o WHERE o.customerId = :customerId
```

and it get stuck somehow, it doesn't return exception or anything. I want to know what other possibilities beside locking a specific row which makes SELECT query to stuck like this?. Because as far as I'm concerned some of databases are gonna unlock the row when transaction is completed.

FYI:  I am using PostgreSQL 9.4, and JDK 1.8.

EDIT 1:

Here's some of the codes which I use to execute the query

```
public Long findListActiveOrderByCustomerId(String customerId){
    try {
        TypedQuery<Long> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("CustomerActiveOrderReport.findByCustomerId", Long.class);
        query.setParameter("customerId", customerId);
        Long count = query.getSingleResult();
        return count;
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And it's called here :

```
LOG.debug("### START CHECK ACTIVE ORDER CUSTOMER ###");
    Long orderList = customerOrderRepository.findListActiveOrderByCustomerId(customerId);
        if (orderList > 0) {
            LOG.error("orderList > 0");
            throw new InvalidOrderException("Customer already has active order");
        }
LOG.debug("### FINISH CHECK ACTIVE ORDER CUSTOMER ###");
```

the log stop at "START CHECK ACTIVE ORDER CUSTOMER", but it doesn't stuck right there, it still continue like nothing happens at all. And it doesn't show any exception.

EDIT 2:

Here's a couple of logs:

```
2016-12-08 12:20:06.616 [executor-1-287] DEBUG com.daksa.tos.order.OrderResource | ### ORDER USING WEB ###
2016-12-08 12:20:06.616 [executor-1-287] DEBUG com.daksa.tos.order.OrderResource | ### START CHECK RADIUS BRANCH ###
2016-12-08 12:20:06.616 [executor-1-287] INFO  com.daksa.beemif.client.PersistentClient | sendAsync
2016-12-08 12:20:06.620 [executor-1-287] DEBUG com.daksa.tos.order.OrderResource | ### FINISH CHECK RADIUS BRANCH ###
2016-12-08 12:20:06.620 [executor-1-287] DEBUG com.daksa.tos.order.OrderResource | ### START CHECK ACTIVE ORDER CUSTOMER ###
2016-12-08 12:20:06.620 [executor-1-287] DEBUG com.daksa.tos.order.infrastructure.EntityManagerProducer | Create EntityManager
2016-12-08 12:20:12.526 [worker-3-2] DEBUG com.daksa.beemif.proto.ProtoRequestMapper | channelRead0(resource: order, method: createOrder)
2016-12-08 12:20:12.527 [executor-1-288] INFO  com.daksa.tos.order.OrderResource | ### createOrder ###
2016-12-08 12:20:12.527 [executor-1-288] INFO  com.daksa.tos.order.OrderResource | branchId 8e55ad56faa240be83b2044d79592114
2016-12-08 12:20:12.527 [executor-1-288] DEBUG com.daksa.tos.order.OrderResource | ### ORDER USING WEB ###
```

as you can see my codes start at "ORDER USING WEB" and it goes on till "START CHECK ACTIVE ORDER", but there's no "FINISH CHECK ACTIVE ORDER CUSTOMER" it came back to "ORDER USING WEB" and goes on without exception, meanwhile on my web page page shows Failed.

Comment: maybe it is still working

Comment: @ScaryWombat I've tried same query in the database using native query and it less than 1 sec for it to returns the result.

Comment: Please show us the relevant JDBC code and also let us know on which line it gets stuck.

Comment: BTW never silently swallow exceptions `catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }`

Comment: @Yusuf1494 The Wombat's advice is _exactly_ what you should be doing.  Do this: surround the code in question with a try catch and just catch a plain `Exception`.  Step through your code with a debugger and you should see what the problem is.

Comment: FYI: @TimBiegeleisen, it only happens on production server, I tried to trigger the problem on devel server but it runs smoothly.

Comment: @Yusuf1494 Then add the try catch to your production code and log the exception.  My guess is that it is some small problem, which will be completely obvious to you once you see it.  I have seen this behavior before when working with JDBC/Hibernate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Alright, I'm gonna try next time when the system deploys to production server, and see what happens, gonna post an update later. Meantime I gonna try to trigger on devel server

Comment: Lets see ... where exactly is your log? You post messages, as does your JPA provider, but then you don't show us the log. Good look with that one

Comment: @NeilStockton I am sorry I can't provide the log,due to my production server has been rollback cause this error really bugged customers. But I can assure you that on log, it was stop at "### START CHECK ACTIVE ORDER CUSTOMER ###",the log itself just goes on without show any exception.

Comment: @NeilStockton here you go Neil, I forgot I've been saved production server logs on my computer